# "Neither he nor his servants HAS/HAVE left"

Tags: conjunctions, subject-verb-agreement

1. Neither he nor his servants have left.
2. Neither he nor his servants has left.

Which of these is correct? 
I think the first one is correct but my friend says it's the other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though you likely know that grammatical rules are often violated, subject/verb agreement with either/or and neither/nor generally follows the rule below.

> The verb in an either/or statement agrees with the noun that is closest to it.

So either of the following would be correct (though the first one sounds vastly better to my AmE ear.)

> Neither he nor his servants have left.
>   Neither his servants nor he has left.

Comment: Note that if it's "and" rather than "or" or "nor", then it takes a plural, because more than one something is involved. "Both his servants and he have left."